# Can we do multiple explode array on one line

Tags: php

> multiple Array Explode,i Want Output Using Explode This Type

1,1000,AA
2,2000,BB
3,3000,CC

```
<?php 
$data1= "1,2,3";
$data2= "1000,2000,3000";
$data3= "AA,BB,CC";

$array =  explode(',', $data1);
foreach ($array as $data1) 
{
    echo $data1;
    echo $data2;
    echo $data3."<br>";
}
?>
```

multiple Array Explode 
I Want Output Using Explode

```
1 1000 AA
2 2000 BB
3 3000 CC
```

Comment: sure you did not mean http://php.net/implode ?

Comment: using explode function

Comment: sry, i do not understand completly, can you give some more details, what you have and what you want and what you tried so far? thanks.

Comment: questions Detail edited

Comment: 1,1000,AA 2,2000,BB 3,3000,CC this is your desire output or you want to convert this string into array

Comment: Did you mean to start with an array containing a SINGLE occurance that contains a comma delimited string? Or shoud the `$data1/2/3` arrays actually all contain 3 occurances like you would expect an array to be????

Comment: It's a mystery what your question is, but an obvious flaw here is that you're trying to *explode an array*! You can explode a string to an array, you can't explode an array.

Comment: @deceze Check what is actually in those 3 arrays. Took me 15 minutes to spot that in fact they are each a single occurance array with a comma delimited string as occurance 0 in each

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, `$data1` was **an array** with a comma delimited string inside it. OP was still trying to *explode the array*. But never mind that, question is edited now.

Comment: edited my post for better understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is explode each of your original data items into an array and then process one array using the index to also reference the other 2 arrays.

```
<?php
$data1= "1,2,3";
$data2= "1000,2000,3000";
$data3= "AA,BB,CC";

$arr1 = explode(',', $data1);
$arr2 = explode(',', $data2);
$arr3 = explode(',', $data3);

foreach ( $arr1 as $key => $val ) {
    echo sprintf( '%s %s %s<br>', $val, $arr2[$key], $arr3[$key] );
}
```

RESULTS:

```
1 1000 AA<br>2 2000 BB<br>3 3000 CC<br>
```

Or if seen in a browser

```
1 1000 AA
2 2000 BB
3 3000 CC
```

Comment: Answer amended to match your change to the question

Comment: Thanks...For Help Mr.RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will help you

**If there is space between string (After AA,BB) then use space (" ") in explode and if there is new line then use \n in explode**

```
<?php
$str = "1,1000,AA 2,2000,BB 3,3000,CC";
$arr = explode(" ",$str);
print_r($arr);

$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();
$arr3 = array();

foreach($arr as $val){
    $value = explode(",",$val);
    $arr1[] = $value[0];
    $arr2[] = $value[1];
    $arr3[] = $value[2];
}


print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
print_r($arr3);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data1= "1,2,3";
$data2= "10,20,30";
$data3= "100,200,300";

$arr1 = explode(',', $data1);
$arr2 = explode(',', $data2);
$arr3 = explode(',', $data3);

foreach ( $arr1 as $key => $val ) {
    echo $val;
    echo $arr2[$key];
    echo $arr3[$key];


}
```